# Bootstrap tab radius missing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why would my Bootstrap tabs be missing their radius corners? In fact they are completely missing their left corners. I did not change bootstrap CSS at all.

Looked all around `nav-tabs` in CSS and can't see an issue.
Thanks

**Missing radius on Bootstrap tabs**

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you can create a demo of it. Use the code snippet here or bootply.com

Comment: is your border on the same element as your border-radius? Are you using IE8? (which I higly doubt)